# Using subtract predicate in swi prolog

Tags: prolog

I need to subtract certain numbers from the given list. I use SWI Prolog. This was what I did.

```
subtract([1,4],[1,2,3,4,5],'L')
```

But it doesnt seem to working in SWI prolog..pls help me....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`L` needs to be a variable, so its name must be without quotes, like this:

```
subtract([1,4],[1,2,3,4,5],L).
```

This produces an empty list, because both `1` and `4` are in the larger list. If you switch the lists around, `L` will be `[2,3,5]`:

```
subtract([1,2,3,4,5],[1,4],L).
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/IPynG7).

Comment: thanks, i tried it without quotes at first and I obtained the error 'Singleton Variablec[L]' and after writing the write() predicate with it, it worked fine.

Comment: can u tell me wht this piece of code doesnt work?

    inp:- write('Enter the string'),nl,read(X),write(X).
    abc:- subtract(X,['at','in','to','of'],L),write(L).

I keep getting the Singleton Variable[X] error

Comment: @User111213 Rule `abc/0` has no idea where `X` comes from. Variable `X` is used in the `inp` rule, but as far as Prolog interpreter knows, the two rules are unrelated. The answer that you got on another thread is spot-on.

Comment: okay, but how do I link the two? I am performing both operations on same string- input a string and remove certain words from it....

Comment: @User111213 The answer to your other question tells you that as well: that's the `inp(X), abc(X)` part.

Comment: @User111213 No, that has the same problem - singleton `Y` inside `con`. Variables in Prolog must be "connected" to each other. You can rewrite `abc` as `abc(X):- string_to_list(X,Y), subtract(Y,['a','an','the'],L),write(L).` Note how you use a rule `string_to_list` to connect X and Y, and then `subtract` to connect Y and L.